# What is the way to fix a segmentation fault (core dumped)?

Tags: getline, text-based, mud

I am making a text based adventure game, where I read from a text file containing all of the rooms, descriptions, etc. The code compiles but when ran it does cause a  segmentation fault (core dumped).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

using namespace std;

struct Room {
    string title;
    string description;
    string exits;
    int exitIndices[4] = {0};
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    if (argc < 2) {
        cout << "Usage: ./mud <roomfile>\n";
        return 1;
    }

    ifstream roomFile(argv[1]);
    if (!roomFile) {
        cout << "Failed to open the room file.\n";
        return 1;
    }

    // Step 1: Count the number of rooms
    string line;
    int roomCount = 0;
    while (getline(roomFile, line)) {
        if (line == "~") {
            roomCount++;
        }
    }
    roomCount /= 3;

    // Step 2: Create an array of Room objects
    Room* rooms = new Room[roomCount];

    // Step 3: Read and populate the Room objects from the file
    roomFile.clear();
    roomFile.seekg(0, ios::beg);

    int currentRoom = -1;
    int lineNum = 0;

    while (getline(roomFile, line)) {
        if (line == "~") {
            currentRoom++;
            lineNum = 0;
        } else {
            switch (lineNum) {
                case 0:
                    rooms[currentRoom].title = line;
                    break;
                case 1:
                    rooms[currentRoom].description = line;
                    break;
                case 2:
                    rooms[currentRoom].exits = line;
                    size_t pos = 0;
                    int exitIndex = 0;
                    while ((pos = line.find(" ")) != string::npos) {
                        string exitStr = line.substr(0, pos);
                        stringstream ss(exitStr);
                        line.erase(0, pos + 1);
                        int exitNumb;
                        ss >> exitNumb;
                        rooms[currentRoom].exitIndices[exitIndex++] = exitNumb;
                    }
                    if (!line.empty()) {
                        stringstream ss(line);
                        int exitNumb;
                        ss >> exitNumb;
                        rooms[currentRoom].exitIndices[exitIndex++] = exitNumb;
                    }
                    break;
            }
            lineNum++;
        }
        // Uncomment the following line to debug the reading of the room file
        // cout << "Line " << lineNum << " of room " << currentRoom << ": " << line << endl;
    }

    // Step 4: Print out the rooms
    for (int i = 0; i < roomCount; i++) {
        cout << "Room " << i << ":\n";
        cout << "Title: " << rooms[i].title << endl;
        cout << "Description: " << rooms[i].description << endl;
        cout << "Exits: " << rooms[i].exits << endl;
        cout << "Exit Indices: ";
        for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++) {
            cout << rooms[i].exitIndices[j] << " ";
        }
        cout << endl;
    }

    delete[] rooms;
    return 0;
}
```

I have tried redoing my while(getline)(roomFile,line)) a couple of times but I don't believe this to be the issue anymore